# WATIR: how do drive outlook web access

Tags: watir

since the emails loads dynamically how do you find a specific email that contains a button back to your site.  This is like signing up at a site. Customer receives email to confirm.

Thanks for the support
BigD

Comment: I do not understand the problem. How would you find the e-mail manually?

Answer (score 0):

OWA, bless MS's little hearts (at least in the circa 2003 version I'm looking at here) uses frames, so first of all brush up on that or you are gonna be hating life.   The list of incoming messages is in a frame named 'viewer' The message summaries are contained in a table lacking any useful means to identify it that is in a div of class 'msgViewerCont" and an ID of dvContents.  So to see if a message exists you want to look to see if you can find a row in that table which contains the subject you expect to see.

(be careful using ID values on OWA.. apparently nobody in the group that developed it read the part of the HTML standard that specifies that ID values are supposed to be unique.. the re-use them all over that page.)

Presuming you know the subject of the message you are about to receive, and also that you keep that mail account cleared out so that it will be the ONLY message there with that subject line, then you can check to see if it exists usng

```
subject = regex.new("subject you are looking for")
browser.frame(:name, 'viewer').div(:id, dvContents).table(:index, 1).row(:text, subject).exists?
```

to click on it use .click instead of exists.

once you've clicked it, OWA will refresh the PreviewPane iframe..  inside that iframe is another one that has the message body in it.

all those frames, are nested inside the viewer frame.   welcome to nested frame hell. hope you enjoy your stay.  (like I said, bone up on frames, you're in for a fun ride)